# Problem with making a USB 3.0 A/B/Micro adapter - detects cable as USB 2.0

Tags: usb, pinout

I'm trying to make a connector for a box of devices that have an Micro USB 3.0 input. The box is just a few physical connectors, no USB hub is planned.

But no matter how I try to connect the devices, it detects them as USB 2.0.

[image]

If I use a direct USB-A to Micro 3.0 cable, it detects them as proper USB 3.0.

I cannot use an USB hub because of bandwidth, I need separate USB channels, all of them go to a dedicated root hub on the motherboard.

---

I tried two approaches: first cut of the A plug from a USB 3.0 A-Micro cable and solder a female USB B 3.0 to that end:

[image: usb A-micro]

Did not connect one pin as it was an OTG detect pin that did not even have a wire in the cable.

This detects as USB 2.0

---

Second, I tried to make a board with 3.0 female-female A-B, so I can connect a USB A-B cable from one end and a USB A-Micro cable from the other end.

[image: usb A-B]

This unfortunately also detects as USB 2.0.

---

From what I'm guessing, I have to exchange the SSTX+/SSTX-/SSRX+/SSRX- wires somehow. I tried to change some pairs, but wasn't able to find the proper combination.

---

This is what I tried, the two above methods on one board. Not too perfect solder, but electrically it was OK.

[image: soldered]

Comment: Are you using a USB hub? (the box labeled "connectors" in your first diagram)

Comment: The box labeled connectors is what I'm trying to build.

Comment: You have to use a USB 3.0 hub or hub chip. Are you just trying to splice wires together for all 4 devices?

Comment: There is no HUB, just wires and connectors. Cleared that up in the question (see updated first diagram).

Comment: USB 3.0 has much tighter tolerances on how the cable is made. It's possible that your devices are trying to achieve USB 3.0 speeds, but when the connection is not stable they give up and revert to 2.0 speeds.

Comment: Could you please provide a picture of your wiring? USB 3.0 signaling requires tightly controlled differential impedance of Tx and Rx pairs to work.

Comment: The easiest solution may be to use a USB 3.0 Hub. This would allow you to use premade cables avoiding any wiring problems.

Comment: This cannot be a USB hub - I need almost full bandwidth from each device. Each cable is connected to a dedicated root hub in the PC.

Comment: Thanks for the picture. This wiring will NEVER work. Do you really have three independent xHCI controllers in your host?

Comment: Why won't it work exactly? And yes, I have a PCI-E four root hub card. It is tested for 15Gbps+ throughput total.

Comment: Can you share any info on your PCIe controller please?

Comment: [StarTech PEXUSB3S44V](https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/USB-3.0/Cards/PCI-Express-USB-3-Card-4-Dedicated-Channels-4-Port~PEXUSB3S44V)

Comment: You may be able to lay out a PCB and carefully match impedance for the USB data channels. Fair warning, this will most likely have to be a 4 or 6 layer board to try and meet the impedance criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Use a USB3.0 hub, it has precisely the purpose. You will save on two long cables. With wiring like yours, you will not have any performance gains since you likely use the same root hub in your host system.

Use of passive adapters and extenders is not encouraged by USB specifications. Solder-down wire adapters are 99% doomed. Of course you can go full-blast and develop a junction box with carefully configured USB 3.0 repeater ICs (lookup Pericom or TI or else), but it will cost you a lot of efforts.

Comment: No, I have dedicated root hub per cable - I do need the full bandwidth here.
But why can't I extend the cable? There are for example female A to B passive USB 3.0 boxes that are supposed to work. Is my soldering too imprecise?

Comment: Your soldering uses long stretches of wires. Even if the wires are paired and coupled, differential impedance of your pairs is likely in 150-200 Ohms, which creates strong inhomogeneity along the channel, even in Case1. At 2.5GHz this wiring will create strong reflections causing intersymbol interference and likely intolerable amount of bad transactions. Also, using 1.8m cables already stretches the signal integrity to maximum, especially when  uAB connectors are good only with 1m-long cables.

Comment: Distance: but I've got a [perfectly working 5m USB 3.0 A-Micro](https://www.ptgrey.com/5-meter-type-a-to-micro-b-locking-usb-30-cable) cable.

Impedance: is there any way for me to be precise enough for this to work?

Comment: Yes, you need to use something called TDR - time domain reflectometry - to evaluate quality of differential impedance (see Tektornix 82000 equipment). Vector network analyzers can do the job too. The best way is to evaluate signal eye diagram at the end of your channel (uA end) for compliance to USB 3.0 specifications. You will need a special adapter, a 8-12-GHz scope, and proper processing software. The level of signal jitter would be of major concern here.

Comment: Regarding the female-A to B passive adapters - they almost never work, for the same reason. Their internals are made of loose wires with no regard to impedance matching requirement. This kind of adapters barely worked at USB2 speeds (240MHz), but are a total disaster at 10x frequency.

Comment: Sigh... just bought a bag of A-B adapters an hour before asking the question. Who knows, maybe I'll luck out and this will still work for me. The hardware you mention greatly exceeds my capabilities, I'll probably have to outsource designing of this connector somewhere else - didn't even think this would be so hard to make. I thought that these issues would arise, but only if the cables were long or I make something badly.

Comment: A-B adapters with 1.8m + 0.5m cables work correctly (currently using around 1.5Gbps per endpoint)

Comment: You must be lucky with your particular devices and the host.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having issues with this adapter, trying to resolve them with their support. USB 3.0 hard drives and thumb drives work, but when it comes to cameras, they drop many packets and fail.